# ASP.NET - Unable to unprotect the message.State with only one callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I'm making an ASP.NET Core server (targeting .NET 5.0) with a ReactJS frontend. I'm working on connecting up an AWS Cognito User Pool as an Identity Provider through OpenID Connect. Unfortunately, there's not really any resources that have done the same thing. I feel like I'm close but I'm getting a wierd, but commonly-encountered problem (see further down).

For reference, I started with the following template,

```sh
dotnet new react --auth Individual
```

and slowly converted the IdentityServer4 service code to target AWS Cognito instead.

My server should be verifying an authenticated code that my client sends. My `Startup.cs` file has the following in its `ConfigureServices` method.

```cs
services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
  {
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE";
    options.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE";
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://cognito-idp.REGION.amazonaws.com/POOL/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
  });
```

My client should be logging in on its own first and then connecting to the server using its authenticated code. I'm using [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) to sign-in using OpenID Connect. The setup is as follows:

```js
let settings = {};
settings.metadataUrl = "https://cognito-idp.REGION.amazonaws.com/POOL/.well-known/openid-configuration";
settings.authority = "https://localhost:5001";
settings.client_id = "CLIENT_ID_HERE";
settings.redirect_uri = "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc";
settings.response_type = "code";
settings.scope = "openid profile";
settings.response_mode = "form_post";

this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
```

Requests are successfully sent to AWS Cognito and are redirected back to:
`https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc?code=NUMBERS_WITH_DASHES&state=LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS`. However, when my server processes the request it gives me the error:

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
       ---> System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I've searched through all the solutions of others who seem to have the same problem that I could find and the consensus is that this error tends to occur when multiple OpenID Connect authenticators are added without specifying different callback paths. In my setup, I only have the Cognito authenticator and I explicitly state the callback path so I don't think this is the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit confusing to see different hosts for the metadataUrl  and authority. The state set must also be handled by the same module that initially sent it.  Why do you have both AddOpenIdConnect and oidc-client-js ? You can't use both at the same time, it will be confusing.

Comment: @ToreNestenius I've tried to set `authority` to `https://cognito-idp.REGION.amazonaws.com/POOL` as well but it didn't even seem to make a difference. Perhaps I should clarify that the server (C#) should be verifying authentication through `AddOpenIdConnect` and the client (JS) should do the login process through `oidc-client-js`. Is this wrong? This is essentially how it works in the `dotnet new react --auth Individual` template.

Comment: Either you do it in JavaScript with oidc-client-js or in the ASP.nET Core backend using AddOpenIDConnect, you should not do both.  With oidc-client-js you do it all in javascript and your asp.net core becomes the API that you should protect using AddJwtBearer. You should also read https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks. That makes sense also I appreciate the article. Now I'm having a problem figuring out what the correct authentication service is the the ASP.NET server. I'm using the Authorization Code Grant flow so the client gets a code and not a token so JWT Bearer Token doesn't work for me. Do you know how to setup a code-to-token exchange on the server? If not, no worries. That's probably for a different question.

Comment: The code you get is stil fine, you just need to do to ask your IdentityProvider one more time for the real tokens and I think oidc-client-js should handle that for you. Using the authoriztion code flow is the correct flow to use if you want to let users login to your system.

Comment: @ToreNestenius I understand. Is there a simple way to use the ASP.NET OIDC handler to exchange the code for a token on the server-side? I'd prefer to have the backend handle secrets and tokens.

Comment: You should read this article, it describes how you secure a SPA application properly on the backend. Or you use AddOpenIdConnect and do it your self. But you can't both do it in the client and in the backend.

Comment: This video is also relevant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck